# flutter starting error: version solving failed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have downloaded a flutter project and placed the lib, assets and pubsec.yaml files in a new project. After "flutter packages get" There are more than 1k+ error. this the error:

```
Because fluttermultigrocery depends on flutter_localizations any from sdk which depends 
on intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2, intl 0.17.0-nullsafety.2 is required.

So, because fluttermultigrocery depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fluttermultigrocery depends on intl ^0.16.1, version solving failed.)
```

**this are my pubsec.yaml dependencies:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  optimized_cached_image: ^0.1.15
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.4.1 #for cached_network_image
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: 4.3.2+2
  connectivity: 0.4.9+2
  dynamic_theme: ^1.0.1
  sembast: ^2.4.7+6
  path_provider: ^1.6.14
  intl: ^0.16.1
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  url_launcher: ^5.5.2
  carousel_slider: 2.2.1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.0



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  #flutter_local_notifications:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the version in dependency which creates problem and it will work
like =>  firebase_core: (Don't specify version)
firebase_messaging: (Don't specify version)